# How do I input join table field in a form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my structure:

```
class Student
  has_many :fruits, through: :students_fruits
end

class Fruit
  has_many :students, through: :students_fruits
end

class StudentFruit
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :fruit
end

create_table "students_fruits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.integer  "fruit_id"
    t.boolean  "own"
end
```

When I create Student instance, I can select the fruits.

However, how to select the fruits and input the `own` field at the same time?

For example:

```
Fruits      Own

☑apple      ☑

☑pear       □

☑orange     ☑
```

This is my current view, I want to add the `own` field into the form:

```
= simple_form_for(@student) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.association :fruits, as: :check_boxes

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: Use [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) together with [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: @max Can you give me a example? thanks

Comment: http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/

Comment: Just do trial and error, you will see (as I have seen myself) it helps. You cannot do wrong by just changing the code in development mode and reloading the page. Begin with the parent element and move to the child element. I'd try `simple_form_for(@student, @fruit)`.

Comment: @max the tutorial is help to add new nested field. My problem is to input the value in join table accompany with the fruit selected.  I don't need to create new fruit. Only select the exist fruits.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :student_fruits
   has_many :fruits, through: :student_fruits
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_fruits
end

#app/controllers/students_controller.rb
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @student = Student.new
      @fruits  = Fruit.all
      @fruits.each { @student.student_fruits.build }
   end

   private

   def student_fruits_fields
      params.permit(:student).permit(student_fields_attributes: [:fruit_id, :own])
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use `fields_for`:

```
#app/views/students/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @student do |f| %>
   <%= f.simple_fields_for :student_fruits, @fruits do |sf| %>
      <%= sf.input :fruit_id, as: :check_box #-> this needs fixing %>
      <%= sf.input :own, as: :boolean %> 
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I need to think about the `fruit_id` thing. The overall pattern should work though

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, the fruit_id is not working. Have you figured it out? I am looking for your response.

Comment: Can you tell me what it looks like in your view?

Comment: It is error. the `:fruit_id` didn't be a check_box. I can change it to `collection: @fruits`. But it will select from all the fruits on each time, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods：

1. use nested-forms：http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

> ```
> class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :addresses
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
> end
> ```

2. Virtual property. for example:

> ```
> class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :addresses
>
>   def address=(*args)
>     # update address data to addresses table.
>   end
> end
> ```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't want to create fruits when I create student. That's why I didn't use nested-forms. My question is when I select a fruit, the join table will generate a instance: `{student_id: 1, fruit_id: 1}`. I want to also select the `own` field. So in this case, the join table will generate a instance: `{student_id: 1, fruit_id: 1, own: true}`, when I create a student, select a fruit, tick the own box.